# Adding custom directive dynamically to ng-template in the component

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am using angular 4 for one of my projects and i have a situation where i am using ng-template to render my table rows as following.

// my-row-component.component.ts

```
 <tr>
<ng-template  [ngTemplateOutlet]="rowTemplate" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ row: data}">
</ng-template>
</tr>
```

where rowTemplate is the input property of the class . And this component will be used as

```
<table>
<my-row-component [rowTemplate] = "rowTemplate2"></my-row-component>
</table>
<ng-template #rowTemplate2 let-row="row">
     <td [innerHTML]="row.id"></td>
     <td [innerHTML]="row.displayName"></td>
     <td [innerHTML]="row.location"></td>
 </ng-template>
```

Now the problem is i have to add a tooltip that will be displayed on hovering the each td dynamically. I cannot use the tooltip directly on the template `td`, I have to add the directive dynamically in the my--row-component as I have other constraints that doesn't allow me to use it directly on each `td`. How to go about this? Please help.

Comment: Can you give us an example of the constraints that prevent you from adding the tooltip in td?

Comment: I can't imagine a constraint that would prevent adding a directive statically.

Comment: Have you considered using Angular Material? Its tooltip component can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the tooltip directive you use is not a structural directives, you can use `*ngIf`.

Expose an object say **constraintObject** on *my-row-component.component.ts* that will be used to see constraints and decide whether or not to apply directive. Pass this object to row template context:

```
<tr>
  <ng-template  [ngTemplateOutlet]="rowTemplate" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{row: data, constraints: constraintObject}">
  </ng-template>
</tr>
```

Use `*ngIf` inside row template (here I am only applying it on location column):

```
<ng-template #rowTemplate2 let-row="row" let-constraints="constraintObject">
     <td [innerHTML]="row.id"></td>
     <td [innerHTML]="row.displayName"></td>

     <td *ngIf="constraints.applyTooltipe(row.location)" [tooltipDirective]
          [innerHTML]="row.location"></td>
     <td *ngIf="!constraints.applyTooltipe(row.location)"
          [innerHTML]="row.location"></td>
</ng-template>
```

You can implement a method *applyTooltipe* on constraintObject that will return *true* or *false* and takes any parameters that you need to determine constraints.